# how to extract data between two specific lines

Tags: python-3.x

How to extract portion of text file between two specific lines?
I want to use pandas python nothing else.
Condition: extract text between two lines 
[Data]    and    [Other data]

`````
 ````
 Input

 [Header]
 Some_info = some_info
 [Data]
 Col1    Col2
 0.532   Point
 0.234   Point
 [Other data]
 Other1  Other2
 Test1   PASS

 Output:
 Col1    Col2
 0.532   Point
 0.234   Point
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more efficient ways also, but a simple approach could be

```
import re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = ''
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text.split('[Data]')[1].split('[Other data]')[0].strip()), sep="\t")
print(df)
```

yields

```
    Col1    Col2
0  0.532   Point
1  0.234   Point
```

The approach uses string manipulation, so you must be careful about data.

Comment: Thank you for code. Its working fine. But if I want to print just one column. print(df['Col1']). it is showing error. Please clarify.

Comment: I have got one solution. But I request you to tell me if you have better option. My code is below:

df[['Col1','Col2']] = df['Col1    Col2'].str.split('\s+',expand=True)
print(df['Col2'])